# Joomla css path

Tags: css, joomla

I'm having a problem whit this website i'm building - www.bodyheat.uk.com .

The first page (home) appears as i "wrote" in the css, but in the other ones the webpage it seems that the webpage cant call the css.

Anyone can help me on that?

TRICAT answered this

**"You must have the base of your urls in the pages wrong because the css and js are using a relative url including the name of the page..
/joomla/index.php/templates/system/css/system.css
And obviously it should be:
/joomla/templates/system/css/system.css
The www.bodyheat.uk.com works because it doesn't have a page name behind the url."**

But where I can change it? In what file? configuration? I saw what you said but dont know where to go to change it :(

THANKS ALL!!

Answer (score 1):

You must have the base of your urls in the pages wrong because the css and js are using a relative url including the name of the page..

```
/joomla/index.php/templates/system/css/system.css
```

And obviously it should be:

```
/joomla/templates/system/css/system.css
```

The www.bodyheat.uk.com works because it doesn't have a page name behind the url.

Comment: But where i can change it? In what file? configuration? I saw what you said but dont know where to go to change it :(

Comment: Try under "Global Configuration / Site / SEO settings" to disable all the options and see if the problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well when I was creating a custom template. In the Global configurations, under SEO Settings, I turned OFF 'Search Engine Friendly URLs'. This fixed my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not great solution. You really need to fix the code rather than hamper your SEO with ugly url's.